# Update OWD using metadata for custom objects

Tags: apex, metadata, package, sharing-rule, apex-managed-sharing

Requirement-
I have many custom object whose OWD I need to change.Almost 50 managed package Objects are there which i need to consider .Is this possible to do it by metadata (package) or what is the best way to do it

Answer (score 1):

The sample xml package will be :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
     <sharingModel>ReadWrite</sharingModel>
    <visibility>Public</visibility>
</CustomObject>
```

- SharingModel Indicates the org-wide defaults for the object.
- visibility- This field returns the visibility of the custom object, custom setting, or custom metadata type.

I believe the folder structure VS Code gives us does not allow you to do the change at once.

[image]

You can use something called MavensMate and Sublime text to achieve this.
The folder structure they give you the ability to make change for all the object in a single file.